# Using DDMathParser to solve string in swift

Tags: swift, ios8.3, ddmathparser, xcode6.3.1

I want to pass a string to DDMathParser and store answer in another string variable using swift. I am totally new to iOS platform so I dont really know syntax of functions. Example:

```
var expr = "5+9*2" //Some Expression
var result = DDMathParser.evaluate(expr) // Result of Expression
```

Comment: This is unclear and/or too broad: Do you have problems with the Swift syntax or with the DDMathParser expression syntax?

Comment: DDMathParser's swift syntax. I think its different from Obj-C

Comment: @MartinR i have edited my question now it might be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how to use DDMathParser from Swift:

```
let expr = "5+9*2" as NSString
let result = expr.numberByEvaluatingString().integerValue
println(result) // 23
```

If you need floating point results then replace `integerValue`
by `doubleValue`.

Comment: It gave me an exception. Shouldn't i be using NSlog function. because in C-Obj i saw that statement is executed through that function. But i am unable to get it working in swift.

Comment: @Bilal: Any error messages? I tried that code and it worked for me.

Comment: Following exception:
[__NSCFString numberByEvaluatingString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9212dcc1e0
2015-05-10 16:40:43.826 Test-1[956:13800] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString numberByEvaluatingString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9212dcc1e0'

Comment: Its v long actually cant copy paste all of it.

Comment: That probably means that you did not add the DDMathParser files to your target.

Comment: But i have imported it. It shows in intellisense if I write DD it auto completes it to DDMathParser.

Comment: Are all the .h and .m files in your project? Is the "Target Membership" checkbox in the File inspector switched on for *all* .m files?

Comment: That checkbox is switched and full DDMathParser folder that is included in my project. But in bridging file only DDMathParser.h file is imported. Could this be a problem?